# Add code just after Post content

Tags: posts, html, single

I am in a bit of dilemma here so bare with me. I want to add something like this code just after the content in a post:

```
<p>Please let me know what you think by <a href="#comment">leaving a comment</a>!</p>
```

To do this, I edited `single.php` and added it after the content. However, the problem is that  many of my posts are separated in several pages by using `<!--nextpage-->` and the above code is displayed on **every page**. I want that line to be displayed only at the final page if the post is separated. How is such thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some global variables available (or not) to detect the current page number:

```
if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['multipage'] ) or $GLOBALS['numpages'] === $GLOBALS['page'] )
    echo '<a id="lastPageLink" href="#comment">comment</a>';
```

The best way to understand what they do is a look at the internals of `wp_link_pages()`.

- `(bool) $GLOBALS['multipage']` is `TRUE` if there is more than one page.
- `(int) $GLOBALS['numpages']` is the amount of available pages.
- `(int) $GLOBALS['page']` is the number of the current page.

In JavaScript you can add an `onclick` handler like this now:

```js
document.getElementById("lastPageLink").onclick = function() {
    window.location.hash = 'comment';
    document.getElementById('comment').focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer and detailing each part of the code as I found it unreadable at first. This is great, works as it should!

Comment: Somehow, adding this code broke the page `echo '<p>What do you think? Let me know by <a href="#comment" onclick="window.location.hash = 'comment'; document.getElementById('comment').focus(); return false;">leaving a comment</a>!</p>';` do you know how I should address this?

Comment: Look at the quotes: You cannot use `'` inside of `'`.

Comment: Oh what were I thinking, added `backslash` before the quotes inside the quotes. Thanks again.

Comment: And you should not use JavaScript like that. Use a real link and add an event handler in your external script instead.

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating how I would do that in relation to my current code? Also why?

Comment: @ChristineCooper See my update. The reason is the HTML-to-markup ratio and maintainability. You cannot reuse inline scripts.

Comment: Got it! Although can you please explain why I should do that? I would like to always understand what I am doing so that I can learn from it rather than copy/paste. EDIT: Thank you, I understand.